# Special Characters from MySQL after using mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string function to avoid sql hacking issues but when I fetch that data from mysql using php, ', " & ’ characters are shown as a question mark sign (�) in output.
I'm using

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you can get help from above link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

**or**

query_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Should I add this while insertion or selection ??

Comment: you can use this before any query

Comment: you need to run this query first